# How to keep my top menu stay fixed when i scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My Website : http://calisyo.com/product-category/?product=?/jacket-2-poche/

i have problem with my menu when i scrool hes scroll also

in this page I want the top menu to stay on the top of the page when a user/member scrolls.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this CSS rule:

```
header#masthead.banner--stick {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so looking at your site, when I played around in the Dev tools if i commented out the "banner--stick" css it stayed at the top the whole time.  I would only use the position fixed and try not to mess with JS to change the css class you the page is scrolled

Answer (score 1):

use below css

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
```